# Django. How to save serialized and validated data?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a `Car` model with `name`, `model` and `serial number` fields. In which the combination of the `name` and `model` fields must be unique.

I am using `serializers.ModelSerializer` from `rest_framework` and validator `UniqueTogetherValidator`.

```
    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=models.Car.objects.all(),
            fields=['name', 'model']
        )
    ]
```

The database already has an entry `{'name': 'one', 'model': '13', 'serial number': 99}`.

I want to add a list of cars:

```
    data = [{'name': 'one', 'model': '13', 'serial number': 99},   {'name': 'two', 'model': '3', 'serial number ': 98},   {' name ':' three ',' model ':' 1 ',' serial number ': 949}]
```

For this I use:

```
serializer = CarSerializer (data = data)

if serializer.is_valid ():
     serializer.save ()
```

I understand that is_valid () will return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in data:
    serializer = CarSerializer (data = item)

    if serializer.is_valid ():
        serializer.save ()
```

Or if you don't want to do lots of queries:

```
    valid_data = []
    for item in data:
        serializer = CarSerializer (data = item)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            valid_data.append(item)

    valid_data_serializer = CarSerializer (data = valid_data)
    if valid_data_serializer.is_valid ():
        valid_data_serializer.save ()
```

Comment: I am using this method now, but the problem is performance. Lots of database queries during serialization. Single create is more expensive than bulk create.

Comment: Then you can override the is_valid() method and just eliminate the invalid objects from the list then return True. It's a hack but I think it should work.

Comment: I edited my answer with another method which doesn't do multiple queries.